# Rules activates but not firing in JESS

Tags: shell, expert-system, jess

I am new to JESS and I know a little of its functionality. I have a program that asks for a students id-number and the program goes and gets the student's subjects.

The thing is by the end of procedure the program asks the user if he/she wants to get another student's subjects.

If the user wants to input another student, It will go back to the first rule that fired but when I tried that, the rule only activated and did not fire.

What could be the problem? I made sure there was (run) of course.

Here's my code.

```
(defrule check-subject
    ?a <- (phase check-back)
    ?stud <- (lookupID (id ?id))
    (student-information (id-number ?id)
                         (course ?course)
                         (subjects-taken $?taken)
                         (year ?year)
                         (semester ?sem))
    (prospectus-information (curriculum-name ?course) 
                            (1st-year-1st-sem-subjects $?subjects1))
    =>
     (printout t "Student took: " (intersection$ $?taken $?subjects1) crlf)
     (printout t "Student flunked: " (complement$ $?taken $?subjects1) crlf)
     (assert (back-subject (complement$ $?taken $?subjects1)))
     (retract ?a ?stud)
     (ask))
```

And I have the function ask

```
(deffunction ask ()
  (printout t "Consult another? (y/n) ")
  (if (eq (read) y) 
  then (assert (phase choose-student))))
```

And my defrule when phase choose-student is asserted

```
(defrule student-select
    (phase choose-student)
    =>
    (printout t "Input Student ID: ")
    (assert (lookupID (id (read)))))
```

The rule student-select, activates but never fires. My program stops there.

Comment: The problem is a mistake in the Jess code. This can be discovered and fixed by people being able to look at the relevant code.

Comment: I have edited my post. Please do help me. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure to *accept* answers if they are of any use. It's not necessary to write "Thank you"-comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write the control part of an application separate from the rules.

```
(deffunction ask ()
  (printout t "Consult another? (y/n) ")
  (if (eq (read) y) then
    (printout t "Input Student ID: ")
    (assert (lookupID (id (read))))
    (return TRUE)
  else
    (return FALSE)))
```

Use this in a while function:

```
(while (ask) do (run))
```

And you won't need the `(phase choose-student)` any more.

Comment: I based my codes from jess' sample program the sticks.clp whereas it asks for the user if he/she wants to restart again. My problem really is that my rules just activates and never fires. It stops there.

Comment: I tried using your suggested code but when I input the student ID it wont let me check if it exists in my database but your code enlightened me. I placed a (run) inside the ask-function and the student-select rule fired. Thank you!

Comment: It would "let you check" if you would follow my suggestions precisely. I suspect you didn't omit `(phase check-back)` from the rule.

Comment: I did mam. My check-student-id rule just activated but did not fire.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "activated", but if you use it in the usual sense, i.e., that it is ready to fire because there's (at least) on set of matching facts, then only a failure to call `(run)` will keep it from being fired.